# Paritioning a SD Card with both Linux and Fat32 partitions

Tags: partition, fdisk, fat32

On a Raspberry Pi with the raspbian distro i need to make an extra partition that can be read from both windows and linux.

So i use FDISK on /dev/mmcblk0 (the sd card) to create a new partition which is a FAT32 partition like so

```
Device         Boot   Start      End  Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1           16   125055   125040  61.1M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/mmcblk0p2       125056  2000000  1874945 915.5M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3 *    2000001 15523839 13523839   6.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

After i have written the above and rebooted the device there is no extra drive or anything listed like the above partition, which i determine by using the `df -h` command:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       885M  442M  384M  54% /
devtmpfs        483M     0  483M   0% /dev
tmpfs           487M     0  487M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           487M  6.5M  481M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           487M     0  487M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           487M     0  487M   0% /tmp
/dev/mmcblk0p1   61M   35M   27M  57% /boot
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/0
```

The partition needs to be visible inside the linux terminal (mounted) and also visible if i pull out the card and plug it into a windows pc

Comment: `df -h` only prints mounted filesystems.  What does `file -s /dev/mmcblk*` tell you?  (you need to run that as root, you do not need to umount anything to be able to run that)

Comment: it lists the all the partitions, including `/dev/mmcblk0p3: data` but nothing more about mmcblk0p3

Comment: That looks fine, it is a partition alright then.  But did you actually create a filesystem on the partition?  e.g. `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/mmcblk0p3`

Comment: if i write `mkfs vfat -F 32 /dev/mmcblk0p3` it returns this output `mkfs.ext2: invalid blocks '/dev/mmcblk0p3' on device '32'`. I cannot write `mkfs.vfat` as that gives me `command not found`

Comment: Figured that the reason for the `command not found` was because i needed dosfstools. Got that and now the command worked it seems as i got no errors when i ran the command you mentioned. But i still dont see it in `df -h` . Do i need to do anything further?

Comment: Furthermore the `file -s /dev/mmcblk*` now gives me this output about mmcblk0p3 `/dev/mmcblk0p3: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 16, heads 4, hidden sectors 2000001, sectors 13523839 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 13182, serial number 0x93fbeeca, unlabeled`

Comment: Good, you figured out dosfstools!  Now you can mount it, e.g. `mkdir /mnt/mydisk; mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /mnt/mydisk` (those are two commands).  To mount at boot you need to update `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Oh stupid me i actually just tried that, but writing `mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /mnt/mydisk/` instead of `mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /mnt/mydisk` seems to mess everything up. But anyways now the partition is visible with `df -h` which means this is the answer to the problem ! Thanks a bunch. Do you want to write an answer for this or should i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed the issue was that `fdisk` does not create a filesystem, it only creates partitions.

To create a FAT32 filesystem on raspbian you need to install `dosfstools` and then use `mkfs.vfat` as follows:

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 <device>
```

In this specific case

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/mmcblk0p3
```

After this the device is mountable.

---

Note:  FAT32 has no uid/gid or access permissions written to the files on the filesystem.  Therefore you may want to use the `-o` option of mount to use the files as a normal user.  For example

```
mount -o uid=myuser /dev/mmcblk0p3 /home/myuser/mymountpoint
```